# I'm not able to print js variable in html

Tags: javascript, html

When I try printing a js variable in a `h1` tag it's just printing for 2 milliseconds and disappears afterwards.

```js
function validateForm() {
  // alert("hello");
  var name = document.myform.name.value;
  document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML = name;
  // document.myform.write.value= name; 
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title>
    js 1
  </title>
</head>

<body>

  <form name="myform" onSubmit="return validateForm();">
    Name<input type="text" name="name"><br> Password <input type="text" name="password"><br><br>

    <h1 id="a1"></h1>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"><br>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I want the output to print the name the user enters and it should be visible until the second time the user enters another name.

Comment: you need to cancel submitting the form

Answer (score 1):

This is because the button type is being *submit* your from is submitted immediately. If you want to stay in the same page,you can either change the type of the button from submit to input.

```
 <input type="button" value="submit"><br>
```

**OR:** Use `event.preventDefault();` to neutralize the event.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validateForm(){
     // alert("hello");
      var name=document.myform.name.value;
      document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML = name  ;
     // document.myform.write.value= name; 
     event.preventDefault();
  }
</script>
<form name="myform" onSubmit="return validateForm();">
  Name<input type="text" name="name"><br>
  Password <input type="text" name="password"><br><br>

  <h1 id="a1"></h1>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `validateForm` function you can `return false` to prevent form from submitting and page from reloading.

```js
function validateForm() {
   document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML = document.myform.name.value;
   return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
Name<input type="text" name="name"><br>
Password <input type="text" name="password"><br><br>
<h1 id="a1"></h1>
<input type="submit" value="submit"><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form is being submitted immediately, so the page reloads.

Return `false` from your event handler to prevent that from happening.

```
function validateForm() {
    var name = document.myform.name.value;
    document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML = name;
    return false;
}
```